# Call Recorder ANE (AirNativeExtension)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, ane, adobe-animate

in my adobe air application, I want to call and record it, now this is my question, is there any ANE that recording phone calls?

Comment: `"I want to record calls"` means you should check if the Android OS even allows third-party apps to do such a thing. [**Android SDK record phone call**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?safe=strict&ei=vh_ZXIWQMtuI1fAP7ZuXoAw&q=android+sdk+record+phone+call)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ANE. It records audio from microphone and saves it as .mp3 file.
https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.AudioRecorder.

Comment: No, it doesn't help me, I want to record calls, and this ANE doesn't record another voice !